# Obtaining data from a self-executing Javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I was using a Grunt library (https://github.com/vicompany/grunt-mustache-combine) to combine some mustache templates into a single file. One of the formats available was "ES5" (i.e. EcmaScript5). This format returned the data from a self-executing function:

```
(function() { return {"key": "value"})();
```

**How can the data be obtained as either an AJAX request or HTML script tag?**

The data can be obtained via AJAX request by parsing the response with eval(), however, I am looking for a solution that avoids poor programming practices. If the Javascript is included as a normal script (via HTML script tag), the data is never assigned to a value.

Comment: That isn't JSON, it is JavaScript. If you want JSON, then use JSON. If you want a function, then assign the return value somewhere instead of throwing it away.

Comment: I don't know how to react. There are so many holes and bad practices and misconceptions that my TinyBrain™ can't handle it!

Comment: This question seems contain lots of JS-related words, but they don't make sense together. What have Grunt and AJAX got to do with one another?